# AppCompat ProgressBar doesn't have styling for light background pre-lollipop?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-progressbar

I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and my `ProgressBar` has `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`. Seems to work fine on *Lollipop* onwards, however on *Jelly Bean* I don't see the empty `ProgressBar`. Once I set progress, I get the blue progress colour, however I still can't see the empty bar. Switching to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` *fixes* the issue but I want to work with the Light theme.

Is Light styling for `ProgressBar` missing from `AppCompat` or am I not using it correctly? Is there a good workaround?

**My ProgressBar declaration is:**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp/>
```